# Show Only Department Changes in Access 2010 Query

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have a table in Access that shows department history for associates; in total, there are several thousand records, and if an employee was in more than one department, he/she will have more than one record. An sample of the data is shown in the attached photo. [Sample Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XU70W.png)

The goal is for the query in Access to return transfer history for an associate, or in other words, the first time he/she was in each unique department code. An example of the expected outcome from the sample data is shown in the attached photo as well. [Expected Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsDhu.png)

Notice, for example, that the first associate (Employee Test1) had a top of stack row on 7/5/2016 that I would expect to be omitted because the previous record already reflects the transfer into 001271 on 5/2/2016.

Thus far, I've created the following query in Access via the Query Wizard (I'm a novice at SQL):

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Multiple Records_1].[Associate ID], [Multiple Records_1].[First Name], [Multiple Records_1].[Last Name], Min([Multiple Records_1].[Position Effective Date]) AS [MinOfPosition Effective Date], [Multiple Records_1].[Home Department Code], [Multiple Records_1].[Business Unit Description]
FROM [Multiple Records] INNER JOIN [Multiple Records] AS [Multiple Records_1] ON [Multiple Records].[Associate ID] = [Multiple Records_1].[Associate ID]
GROUP BY [Multiple Records_1].[Associate ID], [Multiple Records_1].[First Name], [Multiple Records_1].[Last Name], [Multiple Records_1].[Home Department Code], [Multiple Records_1].[Business Unit Description], [Multiple Records].[Home Department Code]
HAVING ((([Multiple Records].[Home Department Code])<>[Multiple Records_1].[Home Department Code]));
```

This got me pretty close to what I needed, but the 10/5/2015 record for "Employee Test 1" was suppressed because he transferred back into 001289...I want to make sure that similar records aren't dropped because an associate transfers out of a department but then later transfers back into it.

I would greatly appreciate any help! Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are probably more elegant ways to solve this but this worked for me:

First create a summary (qryMin1) of the earliest overall date for each dpt.  This gives the same result as your query, without joining the table to itself.

```
SELECT [Multiple Records].[Associate ID], Min([Multiple Records].[Position Effective Date]) AS EarliestEffectiveDate, [Multiple Records].[Home Department Code]
FROM [Multiple Records]
GROUP BY [Multiple Records].[Associate ID], [Multiple Records].[Home Department Code];
```

Now get any other (minimum) dates (qryMin2) which are after the ones in qryMin1. This will bring some duplicates with the results of qryMin1; that's ok for now.

```
SELECT [Multiple Records].[Associate ID], Min([Multiple Records].[Position Effective Date]) AS OtherEarliestDates, [Multiple Records].[Home Department Code]
FROM qryMin1 INNER JOIN [Multiple Records] ON qryMin1.[Associate ID] = [Multiple Records].[Associate ID]
WHERE ((([Multiple Records].[Position Effective Date])>[qryMin1]![EarliestEffectiveDate]) AND (([Multiple Records].[Home Department Code])<>[qryMin1]![Home Department Code]))
GROUP BY [Multiple Records].[Associate ID], [Multiple Records].[Home Department Code];
```

Now we UNION the results of the two queries (use UNION not UNION ALL as we don't want the duplicates):

```
SELECT [Associate ID], EarliestEffectiveDate, [Home Department Code] FROM qryMin1
UNION SELECT [Associate ID], OtherEarliestDates, [Home Department Code]  FROM qryMin2;
```

Finally, join this back up to the original table to do whatever you want with the result.  Here, I used it to show a flag on the records this mechanism would keep, to see if it's doing the right thing.

```
SELECT [Multiple Records].[Associate ID], [Multiple Records].[First Name], [Multiple Records].[Last Name], [Multiple Records].[Position Effective Date], [Multiple Records].[Home Department Code], [Multiple Records].[Business Unit Description], IIf([qryMinUnion]![Associate ID] Is Not Null,1,Null) AS [Result?]
FROM [Multiple Records] LEFT JOIN qryMinUnion ON ([Multiple Records].[Home Department Code] = qryMinUnion.[Home Department Code]) AND ([Multiple Records].[Position Effective Date] = qryMinUnion.EarliestEffectiveDate) AND ([Multiple Records].[Associate ID] = qryMinUnion.[Associate ID])
ORDER BY [Multiple Records].[Associate ID], [Multiple Records].[Position Effective Date];
```

Note: this is a lot of nested queries and horrible summarising. If you're working with big datasets, it will be slow at best, or oversize the database at worst.  You might have to split the results into actual tables, rather than nesting subqueries. If it's for feeding an interactive tool, I would find a way to flag the right records as the data gets collected, instead of working it out retrospectively.